# Connect facebook without login in android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I would like to know if it is possible to login without facebook or any social network already used in the OS without having to enter login / password, like it happens for stackoverflow login in a browser.

I'd like to have 3 icons, facebook, g+ and twitter, and connect user just with a clic.
Is it possible???

Tx

Comment: I have implemented such `LoginButton` in my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.madhur.mapmylocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android facebook SDK utilizes the already installed facebook app to get the users credentials using OAuth. If the facebook app isn't installed, the facebook SDK will show a popup screen prompting the user to fill in his facebook credentials.

Without facebook being installed on the device (and have the user already logged into it), there's no way to get a facebook login without the user providing a username / password. If there was a way, that would be a major security breach.

The reason it works in Stack Overflow (and other sites) is because there is a cookie on your computer which already contains the facebook login credentials, provided you have logged in with facebook on the browser and enabled the "remember me" feature.

Comment: Is there a tutorial about that? or example? Is it automatic or must I program ( Is facebook installed -> Oauth otherwise login window ) ???
Tx

Answer (score 1):

It happens in Stackoverflow, if you are already logged in Facebook with the same browser and the cookie is set.

Similarly, it can happen in your Android app, if the user has installed Facebook app already and is logged in that app.

You should use the `LoginButton` widget of Facebook to achieve one click login

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/LoginButton/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using android-simple-facebook, easy for manage basic stuff in facebook.
https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook